# Create Looping with Customize numbers in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

i want to create an optimal script about 3 parameters in R. These parameters are: n = long of looping, x = any first number, y = any second number. Here the examples:

[image: The Result]

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rep` to repeat `x` and `y`, `n` times.

```
x <- 13
y <- 10
n <- 2

rep(c(x, y), n)
#[1] 13 10 13 10
```

---

Using `for` loop :

```
vector <- integer(2 * n)
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  vector[c(2 * i -1, 2 * i)] <- c(x, y)
}
vector
#[1] 13 10 13 10
```

Comment: Ok it's nice, how about using FOR?

Comment: Updated the answer using FOR.

Comment: That's great answer, thanks.. But i wonder if this question can use Sequence? this is the last i ask you.. Thank you

Comment: `seq` is used to create a sequence between two numbers. See `seq(10, 13)`, I don't think that is what you want here.